# How to do dependency injection in livewire 3 form class?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a Component called CreatePost

```
class CreatePost extends Component
{
    public PostForm $form;
 
    public function save()
    {
        $this->form->store(); 
 
        return $this->redirect('/posts');
    }
 
}
```

And Here is my PostForm:

```
class PostForm extends Form
{
    public $title = '';
 
    public $content = '';
 
    public function store() 
    {
        $this->validate();
 
        Post::create($this->all());
    }
}
```

Now in my PostForm store() method I want to inject my PostService to create a Post. What is the best way to do it.

Thanks

Best I could come up with is to Inject my PostService in boot() method of my Component and then pass it as a parameter in store() but I was hoping if there is a cleaner way to do it through ServiceProvider for example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I wanted to decouple `PostForm` from `CreatePost` component and also wanted to follow the DI principle so I made an interface of `PostService` and used that in the `PostForm` `store()` method. I used Laravel ServiceProvider to provide concrete implementation of Service class. It was so simple but didn't came in my mind.

```
app(PostServiceInterface::class)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in mount() method

```
class Foo extends Component
{
    protected LoggerInterface $logger;

    public function mount(LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $this->logger->info('component rendered');
        return view('livewire.foo');
    }

    public function action()
    {
        $this->logger->info('action triggered');
    }
}
```

If needed add customizations in AppServiceProvider::register